# alternate morality systems in nWOD

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, morality-system

I am looking for systems of morality in the rules, to replace the standard humanity. I've found one in DANSE MACABRE (creating NPCs called anchors) and one in HUNTER THE VIGIL (replacing the sins in the list with character-obsession-related sins) Are there others ? (maybe even in those two books ?) My main interest would be to use them in MAGE, but they can be from any other game of the nWOD.

I'd also be interested to know if some player created a system for this.

Comment: nWOD's Mage already does modify the standard humanity system in a small way, making it 'Wisdom' and slightly extending and modifying the proscribed behaviours of each level of behaviour, so I'm guessing the OP is wanting additional modifications to that.

Comment: yup. I want systems that are not exactly "a list of ten(/twenty) sins, and if you make a sin lower that your current rating, you make a test"

Answer (score 5):

Every splatbook for nWoD has its own Morality system (Humanity in Vampire and Promethean, or Clarity In Changeling...), slightly altering the list of breaches as suits the archetype.
[World of Darkness : Mirrors](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/82477/World-of-Darkness%3A-Mirrors) offers alternative or supplementary systems such as Reason (lose touch with reality in exchange for power) or Conscience (A sort of "Relative Morality", reflects a person's consciousness of how others see him).

Comment: In terms of sins:
Humanity is Identical to Morality.
Clarity and Wisdom are both supersets of Morality.
Harmoney and Psyche are totally different
The mechanics of what losing them is different though.
Even what it measn for a vampire to be liow humanity vs a promethan to be low humanity is differnt

Answer (score 5):

*World of Darkness: Mirrors* is certainly worth mentioning, as Nigralbus covered in their answer.

The *God-Machine Chronicle Rules Update* (see [nwod-god-machine](/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine)) presents an altered form of human Morality, now called Integrity. It uses a new concept called Breaking Points to largely do away with the "list of 10 sins" that you are trying to avoid. Integrity is one of the easier rules to transplant by itself, which is nice if you don't feel like adopting all the rules changes at once. (Perhaps best of all, you can [download the update for free](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/114078/World-of-Darkness-GodMachine-Rules-Update) without needing to buy the GMC.)

*Mage* has yet to have published material updating its morality system. However, the lead *Mage* developer did post [stop-gap rules](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/mage-the-awakening/314-stop-gap-god-machine-mechanics-for-mage) on the forum and, more recently, [an overview of Wisdom changes](http://theonyxpath.com/sophias-choice-mage-the-awakening) in upcoming work.

Mechanics aside, the thematic emphasis of *Mage* morality seems to be on willful decisions. In a departure from most of the other systems, *MtAw* p. 79 tells Storytellers to always warn mage players when a chosen action would call for a Wisdom roll and let players make a different choice if they want. The implication being that mages normally don't transgress Wisdom on accident, but rather on principle -- making a deliberate choice to ignore the full consequences of an action. Thus a sin against Wisdom is often called an act of hubris or blindness.